# Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h -- my Repository URL HEAD"

Tags: git, jenkins, github

When I I copy my Private project to link to Jenkins, I get some error like this:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h -- https://github.sydney.edu.au/SOFT2412-2019S2/WBYWJD_WYWJD_Team15.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
error: cannot spawn C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pass2001326187685754261.bat: No error
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.sydney.edu.au': terminal prompts disabled
```

And when I try to build something there, the log of Confirmation failure is like that.

```
Started by GitHub push by zzho0631
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Team15
using credential ec3b9de9-638a-472d-a137-668b7c1744f8
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.sydney.edu.au/SOFT2412-2019S2/WBYWJD_WYWJD_Team15.git
 > git.exe init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Team15 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.sydney.edu.au/SOFT2412-2019S2/WBYWJD_WYWJD_Team15.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.sydney.edu.au/SOFT2412-2019S2/WBYWJD_WYWJD_Team15.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.sydney.edu.au/SOFT2412-2019S2/WBYWJD_WYWJD_Team15.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
error: cannot spawn C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pass2346010482442283795.bat: No error
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.sydney.edu.au': terminal prompts disabled

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2172)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1864)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:545)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:758)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1152)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Run as administrator:

git config --system --unset credential.helper

If configuration exists for the account used to run the Jenkins Agent process, you may need to remove the system property for it. By editing the $USER_HOME/.gitconfig file or running the following command:

git config --global --unset credential.helper

You may also need to edit the global config file by doing git config --edit --global and remove the line:

helper = manager
Then potentially add the line:

[core]
     askpass =

Lastly, reboot the machine